# How to enter by-name argument to a function in D?

Tags: d

I am struggling on passing arguments by name to a function that has default parameter values defined:

```d
import std.stdio;

void main() {

    void foo(int x=1, int y=2, int z=3) {
        writefln("x=%s, y=%s, z=%s", x, y, z);
    }

    foo(10, 20, 30); // ok, prints: x=10, y=20, z=30

    foo(z=30); // Error: undefined identifier 'z'
}
```

This is quite a basic need. Such a function can have 10 parameters or more and might be called multiple times with different set of arguments. It would be unbearable to list all the args everytime - it would require precise knowledge of positions that can even change in a new versions of my app. Or new version of my app can change default value a I would have to go through all my source code to change it.

I think so basic thing must be in such a comprehensive language like D.

Comment: [Look at 11.](http://pu.inf.uni-tuebingen.de/users/klaeren/epigrams.html). Too many parameters is considered as a bad design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

D does not have that feature. There were discussions about it but I doubt it will ever have named parameters...

It is debatable whether what you ask for is a "basic thing" or not. I am in the group of developers who think named parameters are just leading to complex code. Python is perfect example of that. I have seen functions taking 20 named parameters because over the years developers just kept adding them to the function which became a total mess...

When you have a function with 10 parameters, then your design is most likely to be wrong.

Finally, named parameters introduce extra overhead and affect performance. Here is an interesting article from the C# world: http://www.dotnetperls.com/named-parameters .

Comment: And do you know why? Such a feature do have many languages and is very practical.

Comment: It is only good for quick hacks, in my humble opinion. And that is exactly why you see them (named parameters) in Python, and other scripting languages.

Comment: I have an in-memory datastructure that holds user, another that holds articles and so on. What would be alternative design? Perhaps not to write 100 functions to insert, 100 functions to update and so on. User, article and other records have many attributes.

Comment: Simply use a struct, or a class (depends on use-case) and pass it to the function.

Comment: Make a struct with the parameters as members then pass it. So the call looks like `FooArgs args; args.z = 30; foo(args);`

Comment: You can also use builder pattern.

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew named parameters are so costly in C#.

Comment: I wanted to use default parameters in a constructor or method to have a clean source code. It will be better to directly change member variable value from caller context for my use case. Anyway, D is a fantastic language. I was studying Scala recently and think D is even better because Scala is a bit overcombined and needs java runtime. Definitely these 2 language are far best languages in my opinion.

Comment: @tlama Note that you can have default parameters, you just can't use a parameter by its name but something like `void f(int i=2, int j=3){}  f(4);`  is perfectly possible and will result in  `i=4 ; j=3`

Comment: @cym13 I know. It's just halfway, especially from the usecase I intended. But it's no problem, I can set the instance member variables separately instead of in method or constructor as I intended formerly.

Comment: Also consider that named parameters become part of the public API. If users specify args by name, library developers are no longer free to change parameter names without breaking code.