# Skip a default parameter in D

Tags: parameter-passing, default, d

I'm going through the [D language tour](https://tour.dlang.org/) and when I got to [Functions](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/functions) started wondering if there's a way to skip a default parameter when calling a function, eg.:

```
import std.stdio;

void greet(string greeting = "Hello", string subject = "World")
{
    writefln("%s %s", greeting, subject);
}

void main()
{
    greet();
    greet("Howdy");
    greet("Hello", "D");  // duplicating default "Hello"
    // greet(, "D");      // Error: expression expected, not ','
}
```

I've already looked at [How to enter by-name argument to a function in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582976/how-to-enter-by-name-argument-to-a-function-in-d), so I know you can't pass parameters by name, and apart from that couldn't find any mention of such a feature, so asking just to make sure I didn't miss anything and there's a clear answer somewhere on the internet.

If it's not possible to skip passing a parameter when a default is available, what's the best practice for avoiding duplicating default values?

Comment: D doesn't have named arguments. I guess you could come up with a solution that generates all subfunctions, but for now the common solution is to pass in a struct. On the long run this DIP might be interesting for you: https://github.com/dlang/DIPs/pull/71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot skip an argument, but if you know it has a default, you can automatically supply that default:

```
import std.traits;
```

...

```
greet(ParameterDefaults!greet[0], "D");
```